Why can my computer not see my Arduino Uno?
I've plugged my ELEGOO Uno R3 into a USB port on my computer with a USB cable. However, neither Arduino IDE nor my computer can see the device. When the Uno is connected, it shows no connected devices. The problem is not the USB port or cable; both work with the Arduino Mega 2560 and the Adafruit Metro 328.
The Uno still receives power from the computer; the green LED is on when the Uno is connected. Why can't the computer see the Arduino?

Has the Uno had any accidental damage such as short circuits, cross-connected power, or even physical damage?

how do you know that your computer cannot see the Arduino?

check cable (no reaction in device manager) or driver is not installed (but it would be shown as unknown usb device or similar)

I have some steps you can take to check your Uno and the Atmega16U2 chip, especially since you have extra Arduinos you can use in the testing process.

@JRobert As far as I know, the Uno isn't damaged, but that would explain why it isn't communicating. The power LED still turns on.

@KIIV When the Arduino is connected to the laptop via USB, the device manager doesn't show any devices connected to the ports, so it's not a driver issue. The cable works for other Arduinos, so it's not that either.

Which USB to serial converter does your Arduino UNO have?
